# SQL Database on Android

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, exception

Im developing an aplication to control your Day Pills. It consists on a List of Pills (with name and hour), and you can add a Pill.

The app starts correctly, I can go to the Add layout, but when I click "Add" it stops. I don't know why does it stop; I think it's related to saving the new Pill into the `database`.

I've tried to put as intent extras the hour and the name (to the intent of going from the Add layout to the Main layout) and trying to save them from the Main class (I thought maybe it couldn't save because I was trying to do it from the Add Class).

Here is the main activity:

```
package com.example.pilladvisor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listPastilles;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Pastilla[] datos;
private TextView pastis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent h = getIntent();
    Boolean afegit = h.getBooleanExtra("AFEGIT",false);

    if (afegit) {
        int hora = h.getIntExtra("HORA", 0);
        String nom = h.getStringExtra("NOM");

        ContentValues nuevoRegistro = new ContentValues();
        nuevoRegistro.put("nom", nom);
        nuevoRegistro.put("hora", hora);
        db.insert("Pastilles", null, nuevoRegistro);
    }

    PastillesSQLiteHelper bdh =
            new PastillesSQLiteHelper(this, "DBPastilles", null, 1);

        db = bdh.getWritableDatabase();


    //startService (new Intent(this, ServeiHora.class));    

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT nom, hora FROM Pastilles", null);

    int i = 0;

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
        i = 0;
         do {
              String nom = c.getString(0);
              int hora = c.getInt(1);

              datos[i] = new Pastilla(nom,hora);

              ++i;
         } while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    pastis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if (i == 0){
        pastis.setText("No tens pastilles!");
    }
    else {
        pastis.setText("Hi ha " + i + " alarmes programades.");

        AdaptadorPastilles adaptador = new AdaptadorPastilles(this);

        listPastilles = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPastilles);

        listPastilles.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }

    Button Boto1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Boto1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Afegir.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

class AdaptadorPastilles extends ArrayAdapter<Pastilla> {

    Activity context;

    AdaptadorPastilles(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_pastilla, datos);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_pastilla, null);

        TextView lblTitulo = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.LblTitulo);
        lblTitulo.setText(datos[position].getTitulo());

        TextView lblSubtitulo =(TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.LblSubTitulo);               lblSubtitulo.setText(datos[position].getSubtitulo());

        return(item);
    }
    }
}
```

and here you have the Add activity:

```
package com.example.pilladvisor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Afegir extends Activity{

private EditText field_nom;
private EditText field_hora;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_afegir);

    field_nom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    field_hora = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button Boto1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Boto1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Afegir.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    Button Boto2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Boto2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String nom = field_nom.getText().toString();
            int hora =     Integer.parseInt(field_hora.getText().toString()); 

            Intent intent = new Intent(Afegir.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("AFEGIT",true);
            intent.putExtra("NOM", nom);
            intent.putExtra("HORA", hora);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

}
```

finally here is the database class:

```
package com.example.pilladvisor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class PastillesSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE Pastilles (nom TEXT, hora INTEGER)";

public PastillesSQLiteHelper(Context contexto, String nom, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(contexto, nom, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnterior, int versionNueva){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Pastilles");

    db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
}


}
```

The error says:

```
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pilladvisor/com.example.pilladvisor.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at com.example.pilladvisor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
02-03 15:23:33.492: E/AndroidRuntime(666):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.pilladvisor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)` -- what's on line 40? Something there is null, and shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the member `db` before initiating it.

in line 40: `db.insert("Pastilles", null, nuevoRegistro);` 
db has value null, that's why it crashes.

Move the block of code that start with "`if (afegit) {`" below the code the initiates db:

```
db = bdh.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't intlaize db instance. This is the reason that you are crash on null ponter exception in :

```
 db.insert("Pastilles", null, nuevoRegistro);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
db.insert("Pastilles", null, nuevoRegistro);
```

db is null. You have to do

```
PastillesSQLiteHelper bdh =
        new PastillesSQLiteHelper(this, "DBPastilles", null, 1);

    db = bdh.getWritableDatabase();
```

before db.insert();

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before asking a question you should try to debug your code and read the logs.
Just as your log says in line 15 there is a java.lang.NullPointerException which means you are trying to access a object which hasn't been initialized yet.

In the logs in line 16 there is a hint where the exception is thrown:

```
at com.example.pilladvisor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
```

This means in your file 'MainActivity.java' in line 40 the exception is thrown.

So let's look at this point of your code:

```
33: if (afegit) {
34:     int hora = h.getIntExtra("HORA", 0);
35:     String nom = h.getStringExtra("NOM");
36: 
37:     ContentValues nuevoRegistro = new ContentValues();
38:     nuevoRegistro.put("nom", nom);
39:     nuevoRegistro.put("hora", hora);
40:     db.insert("Pastilles", null, nuevoRegistro);
41: }
42: 
43: PastillesSQLiteHelper bdh =
44:         new PastillesSQLiteHelper(this, "DBPastilles", null, 1);
45: 
46:     db = bdh.getWritableDatabase();
```

In the if-case you are trying to call a method from the 'db'-object. But the initialization isn't done yet. It happens in line 46.

The solution should be to put the code from line 43 to 46 in front of the if-case.

```
33: PastillesSQLiteHelper bdh =
34:     new PastillesSQLiteHelper(this, "DBPastilles", null, 1);
35:
36: db = bdh.getWritableDatabase();
37:
38: if (afegit) {
39:     int hora = h.getIntExtra("HORA", 0);
40:     String nom = h.getStringExtra("NOM");
41:
42:     ContentValues nuevoRegistro = new ContentValues();
43:     nuevoRegistro.put("nom", nom);
44:     nuevoRegistro.put("hora", hora);
45:     db.insert("Pastilles", null, nuevoRegistro);
46: }
```

If you are using Eclipse for developing here is a great tutorial for debuging.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

It is not based on Android Developing though it is a great tutorial and should help you very much.
Additionaly you should have a look on the official thread for Android Debugging for developing in Eclipse with the ADT - Plugin

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html